# Have I put ZFS in a dangerous state by building against the wrong kernel headers?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel

I've reverted to an older kernel after discovering that OpenZFS does not have currently have DKMS packages for the latest 5.12 release of Fedora 33 after a `yum update`.

I used [Koji](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/) with the search term [Kernel](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=8) to download and install the necessary dependencies to revert to the latest 5.11 kernel, rebooted into it, and rebuilt ZFS without issue.

But while removing packages from the newer kernel I found that only `kernel-headers` for `5.12.9-200` was still installed (`kernel-headers-5.12.9-200.fc33.x86_64` specifically).

I then realized that the packages listed by Koji for the packages I'd selected for [5.11](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1747383) did not include `kernel-headers` and I had neglected to revert this before rebuilding ZFS.

Everything appears to be running correctly but have I inadvertently put my system or ZFS into a dangerously undefined state as a result?

The packages `annobin`, `boost-devel`, `perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder`, and `zfs` all depend on `kernel headers` and I am most worried about `zfs`.

I plan to install the correct kernel headers and rebuild these packages but wanted to ask here first for advice.

Also, why is `kernel-headers` not listed on the Koji page for the [selected](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1747383) kernel? Because headers do not always track with the actual kernel release, I had to manually locate the last release for 5.11 which was [5.11.20-200](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1746711). I would have preferred if this information was linked directly by Koji with the other kernel packages as tracking it manually is subject to error.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mistake `kernel-headers` for `kernel-devel`?

`kernel-headers` is a singleton, only one version can be installed.  And you must have one if you ever intend to compile anything, as it is a requirement to `glibc-devel`, which is a requirement to `gcc`.  It defines the userland/kernel interface in `/usr/include`.  Try this command: `rpm -ql kernel-headers`

On the other hand, `kernel-devel`, like `kernel`, may have many versions installed, and is required to compile kernel modules, like `dkms`s and `kmod`s.  And the generated modules will only be able to run in a kernel with the very same version.

BTW, there's no need to have a ZFS `dkms` specific to any kernel.  Different from `kmod`, `dkms` compile a new version for each kernel.  In particular, due to compiler incompatibilities I could not upgrade my zfs `utils` and `dkms` for some after upgrading to `fc34`.  I was lucky that these incompatibilities affected only the userland utilities, not kernel compiling (`dkms`), and I kept using the same dkms from `fc33` for a long time.  Usually I tend to follow ZFS master directly from github.